# is it possible to remove the default points of interest from Android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application that would show Points of interest google map,
i have my own sources so I am trying to remove the default points of interest(like malls,bus stops,...) that the google map show.
i have searched the documentation for a solution and was unsuccessful
is there  a way to do it on android?

check out  the blue bus stops that google provide

[image: check out the blue bus stops that google provide]

Comment: pretty sure they are part of the tile itself

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can hide them now!

New google maps update supports it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features

Here's how you can implement it:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
        if (!success) {
            Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Can't find style.", e);
    }
}
```

In raw directory you have to create a json file with map style you want to use.

You don't have to write this yourself, you can use editor, which google created:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

I don't know which version introduced this feature, but it works at least for 9.6.1.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer . i have tested it and it is working fine .

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to disable them as of Google Maps Android API v2 version 4.3, but this has already been [requested on gmaps-api-issues (#4841)](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841).

Comment: Please thumb up the issue found in the link above in order for Google to increase priority on this issue.

Comment: [If my question's accepted answer is no longer the best, should I change the accepted answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335658/447156)