# Remove bus stops icons from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app for showing directions of buses. And I want to disable all bus stop icons. The reason I am doing this is  not every bus stop is correctly placed in my city and some are not shown so I want to disable all of them and input them one by one using markers.

I searched a little and found this [is it possible to remove the default points of interest from Android google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660778/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-default-points-of-interest-from-android-google-map)

But it doesnt do what I exactly want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.setOptions({ styles:  {
      featureType: "transit.station.bus",
      stylers:  [{ "visibility": "off" }]
}});
```

Hope this help !