# how to get more cleaner map API on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

when using android maps API, the map is full of locations and places . so what I want is a method to turn the google maps API more clear or another maps API  who provide mush clear map.
thanks upfront.

Comment: Have you seen: [is it possible to remove the default points of interest from Android google map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22660778/295004)